# Отправка текстового файла в Telegram

Tags: java, android, telegram-bot

Пишу приложение под Android и возникла необходимость по окончании работы приложения отправлять лог программы в виде текстового файла в Telegram (А именно боту для его дальнейшей работы с файлом). Перелопатил кучу литературы и не нашел решения своей задачи. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)создаем бота, для этого находим BotFather  и следуем инструкциям. там же получаем токен для бота и его айдиху. оба параметра получаем нажатием apiToken в чате бота

2)стартуем бота командой /start в персональном чате с ним

3)если нужны персональные сообщения, то получаем айдишник своей учетной записи, если нужен чат, то создаем чат, получаем айдишник чата, добавляем туда бота и делаем его админом (обязательно!!!).

4)отправляем сообщение таким запросом:
curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/botId:tokenBot/sendMessage -d chat_id=-1111111111111 -d text="logs"

botId - подставляем айдиху бота, полученную у BotFather

tokenBot - подставляем токен бота, полученный у BotFather

logs - подставляем текст вашего лога

-1111111111111  - сюда подставляем айдишник ваш (всегда положительное число) либо чата (всегда отрицательное число)

идем пить чай/кофе/пиво на выбор